# QTreeWidget::clear() throw an exeption

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

How can I clear QTreeWidget?
QTreeWidget->clear() throw an exeption, if before I use this method, I select any item. Also if I use QTreeWidget->clearSelection() before it.

Here Some Code for Example

```
Constructor::Constructor(example)
{
    tree  = new QTreeWidget(this)
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    tree->addTopLevelItem(item);
    item->setText(0, "TEST");
    auto clearButton = new QPushButton(this);
}
void Constructor::clearButtonClicked()
{
    tree->clear();
}
```

If we click on the Item in this application, and after that click "clearButton"
there will be throw exeption...

Comment: how do you think, why you have throw an exception?

Comment: Taz742, I understand how it happens, but question is..how to clear the tree

Comment: @BobbyDillanl you might want to share some code, it might help to find the problem.

Comment: in my implementation, I would use DFS or BFS

Comment: @Taz742  what exactly do you mean?

Comment: here is a my algorithm. https://forum.qt.io/topic/81756/what-is-a-best-way-popuplate-qtreewidget-database/4

Comment: do you know about DFS and BFS algorithm?

Comment: You create a new local variable called `tree` in your constructor. Your member variable `tree` will remain uninitialized.

Comment: @thuga , I see, just imagine that tree is member of class)

Comment: Have you tried running your application in debug mode?

Comment: Yeah, I've found mistake...when I clear TreeWidget. I must check current item if(item == nullptr) in the slot currentItemChange..=)